# Maintaining order of items in java

Tags: java

What is the best way to do the following(make sure that items from List are following the same order as those in ListTwo):

```
List 

harry~20
marry~22
peter~40
jerry~33
janice~20

ListTwo

harry
marry
peter
janice
```

Now the result should look like this

ListThree

```
harry
marry
peter
janice
jerry
```

Step by step :

For each item in List :

> 1. compare first part of the item to item in ListTwo
> 2. if they are equal add it to ListThree
> 3. if item exist in List but not in ListTwo dont do anything yet save it
>      somewhere
>
> continue from step 1
>
> 4. you are at the end of the List add the item(s) you skipped before in step
>      3

I know this much(actually I don't, I think I know), there are better ways to do this I'm sure

*Why did I get downvote, did I miss something ?*

Comment: What does `three~value3` mean?

Comment: @Gunslinger47 itemName~item value, mock names/values

Comment: ArrayLists don't have item names, which is why I'm asking.  The values are referenced by index.

Comment: @Gunslinger47 my bad three~value3 is a arraylist item, which I intent to split to name-value even better to use hashmap as mdma suggested

Comment: *"Why did I get downvote, did I miss something ?"*  Probably because your question is hard to understand.

Comment: @c0mrade - yea, but it wasn't my downvote.  I just gave up on trying to figure out what you were trying to ask :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be easier if you reverse the roles (store the keys in the `ArrayList`, in order) and the key-value mappings in a `SortedMap`, such as TreeMap, or `ConcurrentSkipListMap`. The comparator for the sorted map can use `List.indexOf` as the basis for element comparison.

With this arrangement, the map defines the key/value mapping, which is natural for the map, and the list maintains the desired order, which is quite natural for a List.

Alternatively, use a regular Map, and not a sorted map, and use iteration over the list, and fetching values from the map. E.g.

```
ArrayList keysList;
Map keyValues;
for(String key: keysList) {
   String value = keyValues.get(key);
}
```

EDIT: Commons collections has [SetUniqueList](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/index.html) - a list that ensures uniqueness like a Set. It also has has various types of OrderedMap, in particular a [ListOrderedMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap.html) that maintains the key/value mappings in the order of a list. For generics support, see [commons collections with generics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/collections/).

Comment: thank you for your swift response, I forgot to mention that I can't have duplicate entries thats why I'm using the LinkedHashSet and order is important also.

Comment: can you elaborate on this 'The comparator for the sorted map can use List.indexOf as the basis for element comparison.'

Comment: @c0mrade - please see my edit. Commons collections has all the pieces to do this for you without having to write any custom comparators etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

You can call something like

```
map.put(one,value1);
```

and later call

```
map.get(one);
```

which will return value1

also a hash map does not accept duplicate key, so if you call

```
map.put(one,value2);
```

after this the original value is replaced.

you can use

```
map.containsKey(one)
```

to check whether one already exists as a key

Answer (score 0):

If you are only comparing the keys of element then you can store them in LinkedHashSet and use the contains method of linkedHashset to check whether the element exists in constant time O(1).

LinkeHashMap also serves the purpose, however it requires extra space to store the value and this is not required we are only interested in keys.

Refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html